# Bash Script ouputs Command Not Found Repeatedly

Tags: bash, archlinux

I am trying to create a bash script that will write to text files the output of some pacman queries mainly what packages are installed locally, packages that are installed as dependencies, packages that are orphans, and what packages require what dependencies. Currently, I am in the middle of solving an issue that is preventing my from writing what packages require what dependencies. I am using the following bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e -u

#Switch to PWD
cd /home/$USER/System/scripts/pacman-queries-output/

#Get the current date
DATE=`date +%m%d%Y`

#Pacman Queries
pacman --query -e >pacman_installed$DATE.txt
pacman --query -d >pacman_dependencies$DATE.txt
pacman -Qdt >pacman_orphans$DATE.txt

while read package_desc
do
    package_name=$(echo $package_desc| cut -d' ' -f 1)
    check_if_none=$(pacman -Qi $package_name | grep "Req" | sed -e 's/Required By    : //g')
    if $check_if_none != "Required By     : None"
    then
        echo $package_name >>pacman_required_by$DATE.txt
        pacman -Qi $package_name | grep "Req" | sed -e 's/Required By    : //g' >>pacman_required_by$DATE.txt
    fi
done < $PWD/pacman_installed$DATE.txt

echo 'Completed 'basename
```

However, the while loop doesn't seem to create and/or write to the text file I specified instead it echoes this multiple times in the terminal:

./pacman-queries.sh: line 20: Required: command not found

The following is one of the iterations of the while loop that is displayed when running bash -x pacman-queries.sh:

```
+ read package_desc
++ echo aesfix 1.0.1-4
++ cut '-d ' -f 1
+ package_name=aesfix
++ pacman -Qi aesfix
++ grep Req
++ sed -e 's/Required By    : //g'
+ check_if_none='Required By     : None'
+ Required By : None '!=' 'Required By     : None'
pacman-queries.sh: line 20: Required: command not found
```

Could anyone suggest any solution that they might have to solve this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You've got a syntax error at line 20. See https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS

Comment: Or copy and paste your script to https://www.shellcheck.net

Comment: `if [[ $check_if_none != "Required By     : None" ]]`  the syntax for `if` is `if` *command*, comparisons are not part of `if` syntax but of `[`, `[[`, or `((` syntax.

Comment: Please don't add 'solved' to the title of a question.  If you have an answer, add it as an answer; that's the way Q&A works on SO.  It isn't even clear from the question what has solved your problem.  And consider whether it is appropriate to delete the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if $check_if_none != "Required By     : None"
```

If the check_if_none has the string:

```
check_if_none="Required By     : None"
```

Then it gets expanded to:

```
if Required By : None != "Required By     : None"
```

`if` tries to execute the command passed to it. So it will try to execute the command `Required`. And it does not find such command.

How to fix it:

- use `test` `[ .. ]` or `[[ ... ]]` to do comparison in bash
- always quote your variables `"$varvar"`

```
if [ "$check_if_none" != "Required By     : None" ]
```

Also:

- don't use backticks. They are less readable, can't be nested, and are [deprecated](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).

You script after some fixing may look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e -u

#Switch to PWD
cd "/home/$USER/System/scripts/pacman-queries-output/"

#Get the current date
DATE=$(date +%m%d%Y)

#Pacman Queries
pacman --query -e >"pacman_installed$DATE.txt"
pacman --query -d >"pacman_dependencies$DATE.txt"
pacman -Qdt >"pacman_orphans$DATE.txt"

while IFS= read -r package_desc; do

    package_name=$(echo "$package_desc" | cut -d' ' -f 1)

    # renamed from check_if_none
    # some newlines for readability
    Required=$(
          pacman -Qi "$package_name" | 
          grep "Req" | 
          sed -e 's/Required By    : //g'
    )

    if [ "$Required" != "Required By     : None" ]; then

        echo "$package_name" 
        # runnung `pacman -Q` twice is just throwing cpu cycles...
        echo "$Required"

    fi
# All output goes into required_by - moved it here
# also changed `>>` into `>`
done < "$PWD/pacman_installed$DATE.txt" > "pacman_required_by$DATE.txt"

echo 'Completed 'basename
```

Comment: Possible clarification - "always quote your variables `"$varvar"` ... when using `test` or `[ and ]`." `"Word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed on the words between the [[ and ]]; ..."` (not that it hurts anything to quote in `[[ and ]]`, but there is a distinct difference on whether it is required)